# Guice: How to avoid redundancy in modules

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Currently, my Guice module has redundancies that look somewhat like this:

```
public GuiceModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Provides
  @Named("Thing1")
  String Thing1Provider() {
    return someFunction("Thing1");
  }

  @Provides
  @Named("Thing2")
  String Thing2Provider() {
    return someFunction("Thing2");
  }

  .......

  @Provides
  @Named("Thing5")
  String Thing5Provider() {
    return someFunction("Thing5");
  }

}
```

Obviously, this is very unwieldy. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Could you explain why you are using injection for these objects? My instinct is that this is completely the wrong approach, but I would need to know more about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: How about a `@Provides Map<String, String>` method? Or a [Multibinding](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings)?

Comment: Injecting  `@Named("thing1") String thing1` seems unnecessary if `thing1` is already defined as the result of `doSomething("thing1")`. Just inject `doSomething`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> names = ...;
for (String name : names) {
    bind(String.class)
            .annotatedWith(Names.named(name))
            .toProvider(() -> doSomething(name));
}
```

But as the comments suggested, I would consider either using a `MapBinder`, or just calling `doSomething` directly when its needed, instead of using `@Named` everywhere.